# Need to set SSH key for user with Ansible playbook by referencing a Gitlab environment variable

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, packer

I need to be able to pull in the SSH public key that we have specified in our private Gitlab instance for the specified user; however I'm pretty sure my syntax is jacked up. Oh, it's also worth a mention that this is running in a Gitlab runner (Docker) as part of a CI pipeline. The Ansible script is being executed as part of a Packer template by using the "ansible_local" provisioner and specifying the playbook .yml

This is the related yml snippet:

```
- name: add deploy key to authorised keys
  authorized_key: user={{ user1 }}
  state: present
  key: "{{ lookup('env', '$ANSIBLE_PUB_KEY') }}"
```

I expect the script to complete and my Gitlab variable to be passed in and successfully written to the indicated file/directory. Instead I get this:

```
amazon-ebs: TASK [add deploy key to authorized keys] ***************************************
amazon-ebs: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: key"}
amazon-ebs:     to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5d30d577-4373-f7d2-190d-dd6e2f2e21d5/pre-build-ansible.retry
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
amazon-ebs: 127.0.0.1                  : ok=8    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Also, other Gitlab variables were called earlier in the playbook and were successfully manipulated by Ansible, so I'm fairly certain I'm doing something wonky with my syntax.

Comment: Don't put the `$` in the environment variable name.

Comment: That's how they're injected into the Docker container, so I kinda need the $.

Comment: Not very portable, that.  Wonder whose brilliant idea that was? :/

Comment: Not mine. Just working within client constraints unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are passing the variables of the `authorized_key` module incorrectly. Either use `ini` notation or `yaml` notation to give the variables to the module. Also, check the indentation inside your task. Check the docs for more info.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#tasks-list

To fix your error, I would do something like this:

```
- name: add key to authorised keys
  authorized_key:
    user={{ user1 }}
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('env', '$ANSIBLE_PUB_KEY') }}"
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!